# No visible @interface for 'FIRMessaging' declares the selector 'sendMessage:to:withMessageID:timeToLive:'

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I am using React native firebase and have an issue while I am building my app like below (error message).

```
No visible @interface for 'FIRMessaging' declares the selector 'sendMessage:to:withMessageID:timeToLive:'
```

I read many blogs to solve it but until now, I couldn't solve it.

[image]

This is my pod file.

[image]

This is my package.json file.

I installed the latest version of the packages.

I saw some blogs that are saying about the versions but I am not sure which version they meant.

```
{
  "name": "hemscore",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "release": "cd android && gradlew assembleRelease"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.8.0",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "^5.0.11",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^11.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^11.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^12.1.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.15.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.5",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.3.15",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.1",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.22",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.41",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.3",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "firebase": "^8.6.8",
    "flatlist-intro-animations": "^1.3.4",
    "i18n-js": "^3.8.0",
    "lodash.memoize": "^4.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.2",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.5.3",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^4.0.9",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-localize": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-multiple-select": "^0.5.6",
    "react-native-parallax-header": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^7.4.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.17",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.16.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "yarn": "^1.22.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried for :  cd ios && pod update --verbose

Comment: Yes. I did it. but no luck.

Comment: Can you try with delete the derived data, clean project and re-build the project ?

Comment: Yes. I did it too but the same error happenes.

Comment: one more thing we can try is to delete the PodFile.lock and Pods directory and then pod install might this help you

Comment: I updated the question. (just added pod file). Please check it. Regarding the deleting lock file and pods directory and then installing pod again, I also tried it but same error happens.

Comment: Can you also attach the package.json file to your question?

Comment: I added package.json file. Please check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234804/discussion-between-jignesh-mayani-and-danniel).

Comment: @Danniel did you solve it yet ? i spent days on it but no clue !

Answer (score 2):

The following command has solved this issue for me...

```
cd ios && pod update --verbose
```